# Saving text in text boxes before submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, textbox

Like in stackoverflow, I would like that if a user begins to enter text (lets say a lot of text) and נט accident closes the window (or goes back in the browser) when the user returns the unfinished text will be saved and displayed in that text box.

this without submitting.

Do I need to keep it in session[] or something similar?
Is it even possible doing it elegantly or do I need complex infrastructure to support it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a submit. You could do a silent ajax/jquery submittal to store the information. You could store it anywhere but it would depend on its sensitivity. A cookie generally works.

Comment: are there any other options than cookies? (considering the information is not sensitive at all)

Comment: Certainly, any traditional storage method would work. Database, Session, ViewData, XML. All have advantages and disadvantages which will be specific to your situation and hosting.